# Bootstrap - Multiple modal overlay

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Look at this code:

http://bootply.com/86958

I need first modal should be hide, when i click the second modal

Is this possible?

Comment: Just add `data-dismiss` like this  `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Launch modal</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `data-dismiss="modal"` to your launch2 button like this  `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Launch modal</a>`

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/jXI9lVbFjN

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#myModal a[href=#myModal2]').on("click",function(){
    $('#myModal a[data-dismiss=modal]').click();
});
```

Forked bootply: http://www.bootply.com/HYJ57p1wBy

Comment: Or you could just stick with the suggestion from my comment http://www.bootply.com/jXI9lVbFjN

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Yours uses native functionality and is more elegant. Should post as answer.